# LWUIT List not Scrollable

Tags: list, lwuit, lwuit-list, lwuit-scroll

Is there any way in LWUIT to create a List which is not scrollable?

There is no method to allow doing that thing. Can it be possible?

I get it adding this `List` inside a `Container` not Scrollable and adding this `Container` to another Scrollable `Container`, but I don't like this solution.

Is there any other  better solution than above ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a non scrollable list you may need another component, typically i extend a button component and add it multiple times to a container. The button has the benefits of a list item, in that you can click, and if you want the parent container to scroll it can also.